# Set Path dynamically in Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web-config, session-state

Here's the problem we facing.

In a hosted environment setup, we're hosting the same project multiple times. We currently manually specify a Path in the forms config section of our web.config. However, to smooth out our deployment process, we'd like to set the Path depending on the Virtual Directory name.

Is there a way for us to dynamically set the Path in the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload of `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` that takes the cookie path as a parameter, so if you're handling the login process yourself then you can just pass the path of your choice.

The problem is that the standard `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login` will only use the default path value. You could, however, handle the `LoggedIn` event to fix the path...

```
void FixCookie( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Path = "/my-custom-path";
}
```

Comment: I will test this in the morning when I get to work, thanks a mil!

Comment: although that works, I found a slightly better solution that I've posted about here: http://www.failboy.net/2009/05/set-forms-authentication-path/

Comment: @StevenMcD tried your link... doesn't seem to be active. can you re-post one that works, please?